# How to detect rootkit linux kernel module based?

Tags: linux, kernel

I found this small rootkit source code implemented as a Linux kernel module.

https://github.com/mfontanini/Programs-Scripts/tree/master/rootkit

Basically, as you can see, it changes the `file_operations` structure from the file inode and overwrite the `readdir` function to hide itself from `ls` and `lsmod`.

In that case, how would be possible to detect this rootkit?

Comment: Run a pattern match for that code snippet? I'm not sure what you are asking. Detect before it infects or after?

Comment: After infected. Pattern match would not work, since it's impossible to find the file using simple commands like `cat`, `ls`, `grep`, etc.

Comment: Btw, I know that mounting the hard drive using another trusted machine would not load the module, and then it would be possible to find the module file. But why I would do this without a good reason (suspect)? I was wondering if I could check (somewhere) in memory for some kernel module code "without" a correspondent `lsmod` module file.

Comment: so, you don't necessarily want to detect the rootkit, but this one setting - you might get great answers on the unix/linux SE site

Comment: Rootkit - if you want, @schroeder can move it to that site, he has magical powers here. Just ask him if you're interested

Comment: @schroeder sure I want to detect it! but this specific feature wont let me to detect it using regular commands (unless someone can explain us how... that's the original reason of this question). If you think I would get better chance on unix/linux SE, feel free to move this question to there. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

View proc/kallsyms. It contains most of the kernel symbols and is updated dynamically as LKMs are added.